# Extending Array.prototype crashes

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, prototype

I was trying to solve the following problem which I got on a blog but the program crashes. What could be the reason? and is there any means of solving it? I have read warnings not to extend builtin objects, if that's the case, what could be the reason associated with this specific example.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//this is what I tried
Array.prototype.multiply = function() {
  for (m of this) this.push(m * m);
}

a.multiply(); //this should not be changed
console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25] (expected output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***When you push the value to same array during loop***, you end up in ***infinite loop***, create  a temp array push value to it, in the end add it to `this`

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//this is the what I tried
Array.prototype.multiply = function() {
  let newArr = []
  for (const m of this) {
    newArr.push(m * m)
  }
  this.push(...newArr)
}

a.multiply();
console.log(a);
```

That being said you should not override the `prototype` simply use a function and pass the parameters

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function multiply(arr) {
  return [...arr, ...arr.map(a => a * a)]
}

console.log(multiply(a));
```

Comment: As for the second method, I know there are much simple ways of doing it but "a.multiply();" is not part of my solution, it was part of the original question.

Comment: @Addis  always happy to help :) yeah the second one is to mention that we should be taking simple paths unless we are forced to take the odd one

Answer (score 1):

Pushing a new value into an array in the middle of a `for ... of` loop creates an infinite loop as the loop includes the new values. You can use `forEach` instead as that ignores the new values added:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Array.prototype.multiply = function() {
    this.forEach(v => this.push(v*v));
}

a.multiply(); //this should not be changed
console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25] (expected output)
```